# Algorithm to sort parents before children

Tags: javascript, canvas

I'm writing a drawing application that includes shapes that can have children. When I need to redraw the canvas, I would like to sort the shapes to draw so that the parents appear before their children. That way, a parent shape won't be drawn on top of a child shape. Here is the relevant function (written in JavaScript). Variables prefixed with `my.` are instance variables. `my.draw_order` is an array of shape indexes that need to be redrawn (populated by the code below), `my.ctx` is the HTML canvas context where the shapes are drawn, `my.shapes` is an array of shapes in an arbitrary order, `my.update_rects` is an array of dirty rectangles that can optionally be used by a very large shape to only do a partial redraw.

```
redraw = function () {
    var i, shape_count, shape;

    shape_count = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < my.shapes.length; i++) {
        shape = my.shapes[i];

        if (shape.visible && shape.dirty) {
            my.draw_order[shape_count] = i;
            shape_count++;
        }
    }

    my.draw_order.length = shape_count;

    // sort shapes to draw so that parents appear before children ???
    my.draw_order.sort(shape_sort);

    for (i = 0; i < my.draw_order.length; i++) {
        shape = my.shapes[my.draw_order[i]];

        shape.draw(my.ctx, my.update_rects);
        shape.dirty = false;
    }

    my.update_rects.length = 0;
};
```

My question is: what's the best way to implement shape_sort as referenced by the code? This is a routine that will be called often, so efficiency might be a concern. Each shape has a parent property that contains a reference to its parent's shape. Suggestions for a better design are welcome. Maintaining the `my.shapes` array in sorted order is an undesirable option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would maintain the shapes as a tree. Create a single root (representing the entire screen), and give parents pointers to their children. Then a simple preorder traversal of the tree would suffice.

To implement in terms of your existing design, you don't need to ditch the `my.shapes` array. Just add a `my.root`, add pointers from parents to children, and traverse:

```
function preorder_draw(root) {

    //do stuff with root
    draw(root);

    for (child in root.children) {
        preorder_draw(child);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

Should you require data structures that are more complex than trees, you should check a [Topological Sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sort) algorithm.

Comment: Thanks for the link. That's interesting, but the only requirement I have at the moment is that parents not be drawn on top of children. I'm not defining the z-order for when siblings overlap, so I don't think I need an algorithm quite that robust.